# How to rsync only specific directories and all their subdirectories and files?

Tags: rsync

Let's say I have something like

```
/path/to/dir1/[...]
/and/path/to/dir2/[...]
```

on

```
/
```

And I'd only like to rsync those two and everything they contain to

```
/backup/
```

So after rsync I have a copy of them in

```
/backup/path/to/dir1/[...]
/backup/and/path/to/dir2/[...]
```

I've played around with --include-from=/etc/rsync-backup.conf, --files-from==/etc/rsync-backup.conf iterated through all "include file" layouts, I could imagine, including all those '*' and '***' variants, with '+' in front and without, but I failed miserably.

So: What needs to be in /etc/rsync-backup.conf and how does rsync have to be called to only backup /path/to/dir1/[...] and /and/path/to/dir2/[...]?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with

```
rsync -avPhRL --exclude-from=/etc/local-backup-excludes.conf `/usr/bin/cat /etc/local-backup.conf` /backup/ --delete --delete-excluded
```

with

```
/etc/local-backup.conf
```

containing

```
/path/to/dir1/
/and/path/to/dir2/
```